# Questions about "casting operation" in OOP

Tags: oop

When programming, we usually use some type-casting operations.

When the casting happens on the objects "on the same level", it feels ok. But when it happens on the ojects "on the different levels"(mainly between father and son), it feels weird.

Considering this:

```
Class Son extends Father
```

When`Son s = (Son)father;`, it's absolutely unreasonable. Because a "Son" is not a "Father" anymore, "Son" may grow up with some new properties "Father" doesn't have, the casting operation makes these properties unknown.

On the other hand, `Father f = (Father)son` seems reasonable, but according to [LSP](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?OoDesignPrinciples)

> "An instance of a derived should be able to replace any instance of its superclass"

A "Son" can do anything his "Father" can, so the casting operation seems useless.

So can i say that these casting operations are agaisnt OO design principle but necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting objects in OOP is usually the product of either class inheritance or interface inheritance. One has to always remember that class inheritance denotes an "is a" relationship, and interface inheritance denotes a "has a" relationship.

Let's go over to your example: `Class Son extends Father` doesn't sound like a reasonable abstraction, since every male person is a son, but not all of them will be a father. In fact, the opposite might be more applicable: `Class Father extends Son` because every father is always someone's son.

On the other hand, we could just ditch this whole abstraction and say that we have, instead, a `Class Person` that can either be a male or a female, a mother or a father, and so on. Each person will have an attribute containing collection of `Person` with name `Children`.

In this abstraction, a `Person` will only be considered a `Father` if its gender is male and if `Person.Children.Count > 0`. This is much simpler than defining a `Father` class in and by itself.

Comment: I guess we had the same idea :) I just forgot about the gender, stupid gender :P

Answer (score 2):

I find questions like these always interesting and it lends itself to some kind of debate I think :)

Here are my thoughts.
In class design I would in this case create a class of Person

```
class Person
{
    public bool IsFather { get; set; } // this variable will change depending on the count of children
    public List<Person> children { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a derived class, the class should be a specialized person and in the case of Father and Son, I wouldn't create a Father class and a Son class.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a bad example of inheritance.

A better one could be

```
Class Person 
{
    public void walk();
}
Class Man extends Person
{
    public void shaveBeard();
}
```

Inheritance is the way to represent an **is a** relationship; e.g. "a `Man` is a `Person`".

## Using the Objects

Either of these lines is OK.

```
Person p = new Person();
Person m = new Man();
```

It is fine to call `p.walk` on both.  However to call the `shavebeard()` method, `m` has to be a `Man` object. For reasons of type safety, you have to cast it to a `Man` object; e.g. `(Man) m.shaveBeard();`  The cast here will fail, so it's best to check that the variable refers to an instance of `Man`:

```
if(m instanceof Man)
{
   (Man) m.shaveBeard(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither seem reasonable to me.  What seems more plausible:

```
Son s = (Son)person          //Valid
Father f = (Father)person    //Valid
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: the Class on the left hand side is the superclass and that on the right side is the subclass so if we have this:
Object p = new Student();  //is correct 
Student s = new Object() //is wrong...it's like saying that every Object is a student..
Care must be considered when doing explicit casting as it may look correct but might not work as expected. You can't instantiate your father's private property to yourself.